# Change font size of page numbers

Tags: fontsize, page-numbering, amsart

What is the simplest way to choose a precise font size for page numbers? For some reason the page numbers are 10 points but the rest is 11 points.

This is my preamble:

```
\pdfminorversion=7 % For the inclusion of pdfs
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

% Packages
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, dsfont, mathtools} % Math symbols
\usepackage{fullpage, graphicx} % Formatting
\usepackage{hyperref} % Clickable links
\usepackage{enumitem} % Enumerate options
\usepackage{xcolor} %F or the colours
\usepackage{thmtools} % Changing the QED symbol, etc.
\usepackage{caption, subcaption} % Captioning of tables and such
\usepackage{multirow} % Horizontal lines in tables
\usepackage{tikz-cd} % tikz
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes,shapes.geometric} % tikz add-ons
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

% Formatting
\linespread{1.1}
\frenchspacing
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=purple, citecolor=blue,         
 linkcolor=red, pdfstartview={XYZ null null 0.90}}

% Math operators
\newcommand{\ZZ}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Z}}}
\newcommand{\RR}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}}}
\newcommand{\QQ}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Q}}}
\newcommand{\CC}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{C}}}
\newcommand{\FF}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{F}}}
\newcommand{\PP}{\mathbb{P}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\disc}{disc}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cl}{cl}
\DeclareMathOperator{\h}{h}
\DeclareMathOperator{\PSL}{PSL}
\DeclareMathOperator{\PGL}{PGL}
\DeclareMathOperator{\GL}{GL}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Ima}{Im}

% Theorems
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
```

Comment: `amsart` uses `\normalfont\scriptsize` for all of its page numbers, hence the page numbers will be smaller than the body text. You have basically two options: (1) is to look through `amsart` for every pagestyle definition and remove the `\scriptsize` (either by making a copy of the documentclass and editing it, or by including new `\def`s that overwrite the `amsart` definitions in your document); (2) use something like [fancyhdr](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr?lang=en) to specify the page style to your heart's content.

Comment: Please post a complete example rather than just a fragment. You should also edit your preamble not just to minimise it here, but to remove duplications in your real document. `hyperref` needs to be loaded late. Avoid loading packages more than once.

Comment: Off-topic: The [fullpage](https://ctan.org/pkg/fullpage) package hasn't been updated since 1999 and, as such, verges on being obsolete. You may want to replace `\usepackage{fullpage}` (no explicit package options provided, hence the margins default to "1in") with `\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}`. The [geometry](https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package provides lots and lots of formatting options and comes with a great user guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you employ the `amsart` document class and since your document's preamble indicates that you employ the so-called "plain" page style, I suggest you add the following code to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ps@plain}{\scriptsize}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{plain} % re-execute code of "plain" page style
```

I wouldn't edit the document class file, `amsart.cls`, directly. For one, editing the class file directly, i.e., without first making a copy of orginal `amsart.cls` file, probably violates various LaTeX license clauses. Worse, if and when you update your TeX distribution, the class file may well get updated, meaning that your edits are no longer there.

Comment: no more complaints from me!

Comment: @WillieWong - Thanks! :-)

Comment: Thanks! No clue what this is doing but it works, haha!!